Has any research or analysis been done on prisoners who don't want to leave prison?
In the case of a prisoner who, for whatever reason, does not want to leave prison, would this be considered a psychological disorder of some type? If so, where can I learn more about it and any suggested treatments? If this would not be considered a disorder or pathology then what are the reasons why not? Is it not axiomatic that a healthy mind would want freedom over incarceration? Under what conditions would such an attitude be considered healthy if so?
Are there any case studies of such points of view or even any novels chronicling such attitudes in fictionalized characters? I am interested in any means of learning more or gaining deeper perspectives on such a condition.

Prison provides you with food, shelter, routine; modern prison is not entirely absent of all freedom with incentives for good behavior and to keep the population in a safer state. Especially for people who have been incarcerated for a long time, it seems entirely reasonable that they would fear the outside with a lack of stability, difficult prospects for a job having a criminal record, perhaps threats or temptation to return to a criminal lifestyle from past associates, etc.

This is very reasonable. I am interested in how psychology as a science would consider the case of prisoners who don't want to leave in general--in other words, abstracting the issue in order to advance our understanding of mental function and dysfunction. Does your response come from any particular studies or thesis within the academic tradition? If so, please share so that I can dig further.
